# grab element with same attr and make groups

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<li rel="2001" class="project">...</li>
<li rel="2001" class="project">...</li>
<li rel="2001" class="project">...</li>
...
<li rel="2007" class="project">...</li>
<li rel="2007" class="project">...</li>
<li rel="2007" class="project">...</li>
...
<li rel="2011" class="project">...</li>
<li rel="2011" class="project">...</li>
<li rel="2011" class="project">...</li>
```

and so on (as you guessed). Now, I want to grab each of them on year base and group it into something like this:

```
<ul id="2011">
    <li class="year">2011</li>
    <li rel="2011" class="project">...</li>
    <li rel="2011" class="project">...</li>
    <li rel="2011" class="project">...</li>

<ul id="2017">
    <li class="year">2017</li>
    <li rel="2017" class="project">...</li>
    <li rel="2017" class="project">...</li>
    <li rel="2017" class="project">...</li>

... and so on...
```

basically: take each li.project and take the value of his attr('rel') and then group them (group(myYear)) into array and wrap each array with ul with attr(id, 'myYear') and add another html(

yeah, need help :)

thank you!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Homework's fine here, but you need to at least make some effort yourself first.

Comment: @Jamiec my dog ate it! (hehe, sorry I have something in mind but totally stuck on how to pass from eact() to an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("li").each(function(){
var x = "ul#" + $(this).attr("rel"); //the ul with id ID of the LI's rel
if($(x).length > 0) //if ul with that year exist
$(x).append($(this));
else{
$(x).appendTo("body");  //create ul and append to body
$(x).append("<li class='year'>");// append the first li
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this approach. It causes less stress on the DOM with fewer insertions.

http://jsfiddle.net/huGry/

Now, do it in pure JS ;)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.